# POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/ 405 (Method Not Allowed). XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

contact_form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

```
    const formData = {
            name: names.value,
            email: email.value,
            subject: subject.value,
            message: message.value
    }

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.open('POST', '/')
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            if (xhr.responseText == 'success') {
                    alert('email send');
                    names.value = "";
                    email.value = "";
                    subject.value = "";
                    message.value = "";
            } else {
                    alert('Something is wrong')
            }
    }

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
```

});

this is code

**POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)** error that i face

Comment: Dry dropping the old `new XMLHttpRequest(), xhr.open, xhr.setRequestHeader, xhr.onload, xhr.responseText` literature, and try using the more modern [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)? It's a server error, what's the code server-side?

Comment: We can't tell why your server says that it doesn't allow POST requests to that URL. You haven't sold us anything about your server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.